# How to update status of multiple of commits a time

Tags: github, github-api

Am updating the `Github commit` statuses from `Github-Api`.

`for ex: updating a status once build got succeeded`

Those status I will use in the future. Now I have so many `commits` in a branch, I am updating the `status` for those `commits` individually.

Am referring this URL for status update `https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/`

Is there any way so that I can update status for multiple commits at a time, for example all commits in a branch or all commits in a pull request?